# Is it possible to move cash from TD Ameritrade to Interactive Brokers?

Tags: brokerage, interactive-brokers, td-ameritrade

If I have cash to move, do I have to use a bank account between my brokerage accounts

or it it possible to move cash from TD Ameritrade to Interactive Brokers?

Comment: Did you ask Interactive Brokers if it’s possible?

Comment: Wouldn't TD Ameritrade have a definitive answer on this, while everyone else here can only give you anecdotal, personal experience or best guess? So for example, let's say EVERYONE here tells you, oh yeah for sure, and you try to do it and TDA said, nope. What are you going to do, tell them oh everyone told me I could?

Comment: TD Ameritrade accounts have been converted to Charles Schwab accounts now that the merger/takeover is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all brokers offer checkbook access to your brokerage account. Therefore many people don't have checking at a traditional bank. IB should be able to provide the online paperwork to move money from an external account.
Typically the receiving broker is more easy to work with that the brokers losing the deposit.

Answer (score 0):

Hover the mouse over MY ACCOUNT.  A sub menu opens. Under DEPOSITS AND TRANSFERS, click on WITHDRAW.  You will see:

1. Transfer money to your bank (ACH) 1-3 business day
2. Wire transfer 1 business day
3. Check withdrawal 2-5 business days

Select WIRE TRANSFER

Under TO OUTBOUND WIRE CONNECTION, select CREATE OUTBOUND WIRE CONNECTION and follow the instructions to establish the link.  There may be a fee.  If so, you can avoid it by sending the money to your bank (ACH) and then from your bank to IBKR.  Also, check out what IBKR allows.

Comment: My experience, admittedly limited, is that the receiving broker will have an easier way to pull the money from the other broker. In my case, Fidelity doesn't seem to have a 'send' option, but Schwab has an easy 'move your money to us' option. Money, stock, etfs. Just not the proprietary fund in my 401(k).

Comment: Once a link is established, ACH transfers are easy to send in either direction.